# Separate WebApi from Angular to two different projects

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Now I use webApi and Angular apps such one project by default from VS. I want to separate it for two projects. I remove all from my StarUP file related with SPA. I run Angular part with command `nmp run start` and it run in 4200. I add `${environment.apiUrl}/api` for my api request by this way

```
async loginUser(login: Login): Promise<any> {
return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/${environment.apiVersion}/userAuth/login`, login).toPromise();
```

And I see in the networking `Request URL: https://localhost:44347/api/v1.0/userAuth/login`

but I have cors error. My header look like this in network.

[image]

When I came back to one monolit project angular and webApi and ran it. In network my header look like this.

As you can see in first case I dont have fully header. How I can run my angular app separate from web api such a full single app? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are running as Asp.Net Core or 5+ application you have two ways of doing this:

## 1 - [Enable CORS on your web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

This is ideal when you will serve your api and angular aplication from different servers in production.
In **development** your URLs will be:
Angular: https://localhost:4002 (**you will use this one in your browser**)
WebApi: https://localhost:44347

Statup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Any",
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
            
        options.AddPolicy("Production",
            builder => 
            { 
                builder.WithOrigins("https://your-angular-domain.com", "https://your-other-domain.com"); 
            });
    }

    // Your other services
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseCors("Any"); // Allow any origin
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseCors("Production"); // Only allow specific origins
        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    }
    // Your other middlewares....
}
```

## 2. [Use Spa Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#run-ng-serve-independently)

This is ideal when you will serve your WebAPi and angular app from the same server in production.

In **development** your URLs will be:
Angular: https://localhost:4002
WebApi: https://localhost:44347 (**you will use this one in your browser**)
Statup.cs

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Your other middlewares....

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) // In production your angular app and web api will already be at the same server, or you should enable CORS
        {
            spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4001");
        }
    });
}
```